# Differentiation of an improper integral

Tags: integration, derivatives, improper-integrals, parametric

Given a function defined like this:

$$y(t) = \int_{-\infty}^t f(x) dx$$

(which i suppose is called *parametric integral*)

How can I calculate $y'(t)$ ?

I tried to take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) page and I found this formula:

$${d \over dx} \int_{f_1(x)}^{f_2(x)}g(t)dt = g(f_2(x))f_2'(x) - g(f_1(x))f_1'(x)$$

(which I suppose is one of the Leibniz integral rule) but I don't know if this can be applied to my case because the lower bound of the integral is indefinite.

Comment: The way you wrote it it is not a parametric integral. It can be put in the form of a parametric one but it won't help you. You may prove that $y'=f$ using the uniform continuity of $f$.

Comment: What I think is that $$\frac{d}{dx}(-\infty)=0$$   but not sure if that's a legal move.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: assuming that the function is well defined then you have that

$$
\int_{-\infty }^t f=K+\int_{0}^t f
$$

for $K:=\int_{-\infty }^0 f$. Then, if $f$ is continuous, you can apply the fundamental theorem of calculus. However if $f$ is not continuous at most you can apply Lebesgue's differentiation theorem.

Comment: What if $f(x)$ is the Dirac delta function ? Is your statement still valid ? I'm not sure if we can consider it as "continuous" function.

Comment: the "Dirac delta function" is a measure, not a function, so it will be different. In my previous answer Im assuming standard integration using the Lebesgue measure, if we consider the integral as a Lebesgue integral

Comment: Sorry but I'm not getting it. Can I still use the fundamental theorem of calculus with the Dirac delta function ?

Comment: @Bemi no, you can't

Comment: Ok so what options are left to proof the case $f(x) = \delta(x)$  ? Note that  if $f(x)$ is the Dirac delta function then $y(t)$ becomes the Heaviside step function. Why $\delta(x)$ can't be considered as a Lebesgue integral ? After all it is a single variable and positive valued function and it's integral is finite and equal to $0$ or $1$ depending on $t$.

Comment: the Dirac measure is not absolutely continuous respect to the Lebesgue measure, this is why you can't apply the Lebesgue's differentiation theorem (neither the fundamental theorem of calculus). Also, the distributional derivative of the Dirac measure is the measure defined by the Heaviside function, but a distributional derivative is a different thing than a standard derivative.